# Navbar é alterada com scrolling

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap

Estou tentando fazer com que minha navbar se altere quando eu fizer scroll down. 
Até agora, tenho o seguinte código HTML:

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top">
    <div class="container">
        <!-- Brand and toggle get grouped for better mobile display -->
        <div class="navbar-header page-scroll">
            <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
                <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            </button>
            <img src="img/portfolio/logopequeno.png"  style="display:inline" class="img-responsive">
            <a class="navbar-brand" style="display:inline" href="#page-top"> TEXTO EXEMPLO</a>
        </div>

        <!-- Collect the nav links, forms, and other content for toggling -->
        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
                <li class="hidden">
                    <a href="#page-top"></a>
                </li>
                <li class="page-scroll">
                    <a href="#portfolio">COMO FUNCIONA</a>
                </li>
                <li class="page-scroll">
                    <a href="#about">ASSISTA</a>
                </li>
                <li class="page-scroll">
                    <a href="#contact">APOIE</a>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
        <!-- /.navbar-collapse -->
    </div>
    <!-- /.container-fluid -->
</nav>
```

E javascript:

```
$(function() {
    $('body').on('click', '.page-scroll a', function(event) {
        var $anchor = $(this);
        $('html, body').stop().animate({
            scrollTop: $($anchor.attr('href')).offset().top
        }, 1500, 'easeInOutExpo');
        event.preventDefault();
    });
});
```

Quando faço scroll down, a navbar e o texto "TEXTO EXEMPLO" ficam menores, porém a imagem não é alterada.

O que gostaria de fazer é ao fazer o scroll down, que o texto suma e que fique apenas a imagem, mas de tamanho menor (50% do original)

É possível?

Comment: Crie classes (ex. .img-resposive--scrolldown) e adicione/remover nos elementos que serão alterados toda vez que o scroll se movimentar, verificando seu atributo top para validar.

Comment: Pode mostrar como faço no código que postei? Ainda não domino javascript muito bem

Answer (score 1):

Atribuindo a função `scroll()` ao objeto window toda vez que o scroll se mexer ela será disparada verificando se o `scrollTop()` da window é maior que 100, se for adicionará as classes que alteram a aparência dos elementos, se não removerá.

```
$(window).scroll(function() {
    if($(window).scrollTop() > 100) {
        $('.img-resposive').addClass('img-resposive--scrolldown');
        $('.navbar-brand').addClass('navbar-brand--scrolldown');
    } else {
        $('.img-resposive').removeClass('img-resposive--scrolldown');
        $('.navbar-brand').removeClass('navbar-brand--scrolldown');
    }
});


.img-resposive--scrolldown {
    width: 20px;
}

.navbar-brand--scrolldown {
    display: none;
}
```